# Vue native: npm run watch:android

Tags: npm, npm-run, vue-native

I have some problems with `npm run watch:<platform>`
I've already done:

> $ npm install -g @vue/cli @vue/cli-init
>
> $ vue init nativescript-vue/vue-cli-template
>
> $ cd project-name
>
> $ npm install

And for the next step I have this:
```λ npm run watch:android

test-vue-native@1.0.0 watch:android C:\git\test-vue-native

npm run watch -- --env.android

test-vue-native@1.0.0 watch C:\git\test-vue-native
 webpack --watch --env.tnsAction run "--env.android"

info: Copying NativeScript plugins to template dependencies...
info: Preparing NativeScript application from template...
npm WARN test-vue-native@ No repository field.

info: Bundling application for android...

Webpack is watching the files…

Executing post-build scripts
info: Running NativeScript application...
error: uncaughtException: Command failed: node launch.js run android
 date=Mon Jul 09 2018 18:04:18 GMT+0300 (Moscow Standard Time), pid=22308, uid=null, gid=null, cwd=C:\git\test-vue-native, execPath=C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe, version=v10.6.0, argv=[C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe, C:\git\test-vue-native\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js, --watch, --env.tnsAction, run, --env.android], rss=174575616, heapTotal=148561920, heapUsed=97997008, external=956561, loadavg=[0, 0, 0], uptime=3893667, trace=[column=12, file=child_process.js, function=ChildProcess.exithandler, line=291, method=exithandler, native=false, column=13, file=events.js, function=ChildProcess.emit, line=182, method=emit, native=false, column=16, file=internal/child_process.js, function=maybeClose, line=961, method=null, native=false, column=11, file=internal/child_process.js, function=Socket.stream.socket.on, line=380, method=on, native=false, column=13, file=events.js, function=Socket.emit, line=182, method=emit, native=false, column=12, file=net.js, function=Pipe._handle.close, line=598, method=close, native=false], stack=[Error: Command failed: node launch.js run android, ,     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:291:12),     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13),     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:961:16),     at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:380:11),     at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13),     at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:598:12)]
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! test-vue-native@1.0.0 watch: `webpack --watch --env.tnsAction run "--env.android"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the test-vue-native@1.0.0 watch script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\gvolkov\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-07-09T15_04_18_803Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! test-vue-native@1.0.0 watch:android: `npm run watch -- --env.android`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the test-vue-native@1.0.0 watch:android script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\gvolkov\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-07-09T15_04_18_856Z-debug.log```

What can helps me?

P.S.: I'm using windows x64

Answer (score 0):

"NativeScript Advanced Setup: Windows" helps me
https://docs.nativescript.org/start/ns-setup-win